# ASP.NET MVC Binding master - detail always null

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have class, Master with 10 properties, and Detail with 7 properties. Then I create view includes 5 of Master properties and 4 Detail properties as detail item. When I post data, model binding always null. Should I post all properties (Master and Detail) for binding model ?

If Master and Detail class are complex model include reference model and use required attribute, should I define all required reference objects?

I post data using jquery ajax.

Example:
**Model:**

```
public class Master {
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string RefA { get; set; }
    public string RefB { get; set; }
    
    public OtherClass1 OC1 { get; set; }
    
    public Detail detail { get; set; }
}

public class Detail {
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int RefC { get; set; }
    public int RefD { get; set; }
    public int RefE { get; set; }
    
    public OtherClass2 OC2 { get; set; }
}

public class OtherClass1 {
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "code is required")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class OtherClass2 {
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public OtherClass3 OC3 {get; set; }
}

public class OtherClass3 {
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "code is required")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I post

> Master.Code,  Master.Name,  Master.OtherClass1.Code  as header
>
> and  Detail.Code,  Detail.Name,  Detail.RefC,  Detail.OC2.Code  as
> detail (collection)

Comment: I would be a big improvement of the question if you included all relevant code, since the reason of why it's null can be many

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I have edit my question

Comment: You certainly have to post  the view, the actions, get and post and ajax too